# How to retrieve IV from an Encrypted string, then decrypt that string using AES128

Tags: c#, encryption

I know very little about Encryption, but my goal is to essentially decrypt strings. I have been given the AES(128) key.

However, I must retrieve the IV from the Encrypted string, which is the first 16 bits.

Heres the doc for salesforce for more information (if what i explained was incorrect)

> Encrypts the blob *clearText* using the specified algorithm and private
>   key. Use this method when you want Salesforce to generate the
>   initialization vector for you. It is stored as the first 128 bits (16
>   bytes) of the encrypted blob

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm (encryptWithManagedIV)

For Retrieving the IV I've tried something like this (I don't believe it's right though):

```
public string retrieveIv()
        {
            string iv = "";
            string input = "bwZ6nKpBEsuAKM8lDTYH1Yl69KkHN1i3XehALbfgUqY=";
            byte[] bytesToEncode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

            for(int i = 0; i <= 15; i++){
                iv += bytesToEncode[i].ToString(); ;
            }

            return iv;
        }
```

(Just ignore the fact that the input is hardcoded and not parameterized; easier for testing purposes)

Then use the Best answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net) to decrypt the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IV shouldn't be expressed as a string - it should be as a byte array, as per the [`AesManaged.IV` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.iv.aspx).

Also, using `Encoding.UTF8` is almost certainly wrong. I suspect you want:

```
public static byte[] RetrieveIv(string encryptedBase64)
{
    // We don't need to base64-decode everything... just 16 bytes-worth
    encryptedBase64 = encryptedBase64.Substring(0, 24);

    // This will be 18 bytes long (4 characters per 3 bytes)
    byte[] encryptedBinary = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedBase64);
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];

    Array.Copy(encryptedBinary, 0, iv, 0, 16);
    return iv;
}
```

Comment: @Richard: You've got it the wrong way round: it takes 4 characters within base64 to store 3 bytes. Usually, encrypted data is converted to text using base64. A char is most certainly *not* equal to a byte.

Comment: @JonSkeet .. shouldn't that be? byte[] iv = new byte[15]; .. it needs to be 16 bytes array so if you put in 16, it will be 17 bytes array starting from 0, isn't?

Comment: @LaurenceNyein: No, that's not how arrays in C# work. You ask for a 16 byte array, you get a 16 byte array.